# React access out-of-scope variable in setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Currently I'm having a bit of trouble with changing an existing state.

```
    const [selectedFormulas, setSelectedFormulas] = useState([]);

    const searchForFormula = (event) => {
        setSelectedFormulas((selectedFormulas) => {
            return selectedFormulas.concat([event.target.value]);
        });
    }
```

What i want to achieve is that the `selectedFormulas` becomes `[selectedFormulas, event.target.value]`.

The event is out of scope inside the setState, but is there any way I can access the event, or achieve the result I want another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract value out of the event and pass the variable

```
const searchForFormula = (event) => {
        let value = event.target.value;
        setSelectedFormulas((selectedFormulas) => {
            return selectedFormulas.concat([value]);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    const [selectedFormulas, setSelectedFormulas] = useState([]);

    const searchForFormula = (event) => {
    const {value} = event.target;
        setSelectedFormulas([...selectedFormulas, value]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define an arrow fnc here, it's just assign new value for selectedFormulas in fnc update state setSelectedFormulas()

```
    const searchForFormula = (event) => {
        const newValue = event.target.value;
        setSelectedFormulas(selectedFormulas.concat([newValue]));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! There is some more logic in the function though, but I stripped it for this question, that's why it's still an arrow function :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use event.persist();

```html
const searchForFormula = (event) => { event.persist(); setSelectedFormulas((selectedFormulas) => { return selectedFormulas.concat([event.target.value]); }); }
```